# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

ОАО «...», по заказу ОАО «...», разработал комплект конструкторской документации...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет никакой необходимости в постановке запятых. Это разные члены предложения

Answer (score 0):

> ОАО «...», по заказу ОАО «...»,
> разработал комплект конструкторской
> документации...

Запятые не нужны. Нужна буква "о":

*ОАО... разработал**о**...*

Comment: ПОЯСНЕНИЕ для Алёнки:

Открытое акционерное общество "Топор" разработал(?)...

ПРАВИЛЬНО: разработало.